# Unable to verify account name or password mac high sierra 10.13.4

Tags: macos, email

I am integrating local mail into Mail app of Mac.
Before High Sierra it was working fine but after updating it's unable to configure the POP server with port 110/111/995.

[image]

[image]
Anyone having any suggestion or answer then it will be very appreciable.

Comment: What interface are you using to interact with Mail.app? Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: I would suggest clear up all the entries in Key chain related to your server and then try again

Comment: Tarun Lalwani & Charles Srstka, I didn't find any entry into keychain related to my custom email configuration. You can check out an error that POP server can't connecting to server. Please check the question for another image.

Comment: How is this relevant to coding? Maybe you should find a Mac software discussion forum.

Comment: This question is better suited to apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

If you search for ["high sierra unable to verify account name or password"](https://www.google.com/search?q=high%20sierra%20unable%20to%20verify%20account%20name%20or%20password) in Google there are a lot of helpful resources.

Maybe you find one of those articles helpful:

- [How to solve the Apple mail Unable to verify account name or password issue](http://simoncox.com/article/how-to-solve-the-apple-mail-unable-to-verify-account-name-or-password-issue)
- [Unable to verify account name or password despite using correct details](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254715/unable-to-verify-account-name-or-password-despite-using-correct-details)